# Eclipse JDT 4.2 + Groovy-eclipse 2.7.0 + Zend Studio 9.0.3 breaks Zend studio

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, groovy

I am developing a project with PHP and Maven, and am wanting to use the gmaven plugin to do some fiddly parts of my maven setup. After getting sick of using the run, log, rinse, repeat debug method I decided to install groovy-eclipse, but unfortunately doing so causes zend studio to cease functioning. I have poked around through the error messages but it is not very clear what precisely has broken, only that all of the php functionality (and most of my other plugins, eg. css tools) haveenter code here disappeared.

There were no error messages when I installed groovy, and i have since tried starting with a fresh Eclipse 4.2 install, then installing groovy, then installing zend studio. Same result.

The approximately relevant log messages are:

```
!SESSION 2012-07-03 19:13:20.130 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_AU
Command-line arguments:  -data C:\Users\F.Master\dev\binu -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-07-03 19:13:29.286
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI:     bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.tools.css.spy/org.eclipse.e4.tools.css.spy.OpenSpyHandler

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-07-03 19:13:29.286
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.tools.css.spy/org.eclipse.e4.tools.css.spy.OpenScratchpadHandler

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-07-03 19:13:29.287
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.liveeditor/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.liveeditor.OpenLiveDialogHandler

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2012-07-03 19:13:33.448
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui//icons/xmldoc.gif".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui//icons/xmldoc.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.protocol.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:112)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:227)
...
```

and lots more similar missing icons...
along with

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2012-07-03 19:13:40.790
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate provider org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature for project maven-remote-resources-plugin.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.team.core.TeamException: Could not instantiate provider    org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature for project maven-remote-resources-plugin.
at     org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapNewProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:165)
at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapExistingProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:235)
at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.getProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:507)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSLightweightDecorator.isMappedToCVS(CVSLightweightDecorator.java:192)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSLightweightDecorator.decorate(CVSLightweightDecorator.java:147)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2012-07-03 19:13:40.792
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate provider org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature for project maven-remote-resources-plugin.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-07-03 19:14:00.852
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.rse.core.search.searchActionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-07-03 19:14:00.853
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set:    com.zend.php.ui.actions.UntitledPHPDocumentActionSet
```

All this really tells me is that the plugins havent loaded.

The configuration log does NOT show the missing features/plugins, but the "Installed software" pane DOES.

**confuse**

Comment: What version of groovy-eclipse are you using?  I also think there are some interesting bits of your log file that are not here.  Can you delete your entire log file, restart, and then place the entire log file somewhere and I'll have a look at it.  Also interesting to see is your entire configuration.  Help -> About Eclipse -> Configuration.  Put this on pastebin or somewhere like that and I'll have a peek.

Comment: Great, thanks. Heres the log: http://pastebin.com/xzdqcFKY, and here is the config in 3 bits: http://pastebin.com/vWrJKiQQ http://pastebin.com/CqC8H3yW http://pastebin.com/4YdZ6FfK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through your logs, I see several things:

1. You have Eclipse installed in your program files directory.  This is a read-only directory and some plugins don't play nice with read-only directories.
2. Groovy-Eclipse is not installed.
3. This log entry is curious.  Not sure why -clean couldn't be done.

   ```
   !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-04 10:26:46.855
   !MESSAGE The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Users\F.Master\.eclipse_groooovy\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi
   ```
4. There are a bunch of images that can't be read.  Again, not sure why this is happening, but most likely the location of the eclipse configuration area is not being found (because configuration is split between C:\Program Files and C:\Users\F.Master.eclipse_groooovy)

I'd recommend unzipping a new Eclipse in a writable directory and re-install Zend, groovy-eclipse and any other plugins you have. You can keep using the old workspace.

(Also, I'd recommend using the released version of Groovy-Eclipse 2.7.0, just came out today.)

Comment: Thanks! I reinstalled eclipse in my home directory and it now works. This seems like a bug somewhere however: although my eclipse was installed in Program Files, it was owned by me and i could happily write to it. Furthermore, I set my configuration directory to ~/.eclipse/configuration, so all of the plugins were installed there. Could it be that the problem was in fact having the two separated?

Comment: Yes.  Having a separate configuration directory is likely the cause of the problem.  C:\Program Files is a special directory in windows.  Even though it is set to be writable, it really isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...this is beginning to sound like groovy has specified activity filters that turn everything else off. Why?! Tomorrow I'll dig out the source and see if i can undo some of those things, or at least expose them in the capabilities page. (Zend does the same with the XDebug feature).

Comment: Groovy-Eclipse does not use activity filters, so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new workspace. Worked for me. It seems eclispe has problems like this if somehow it is not closed and opened properly.